# What would the answer to multiplying $0$ by $\ln(0)$ be?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

I was trying to find the solutions to $s^3\ln(s)=0$ and came to the conclusion that there were $2$ answers: $s=0$ and $s=1$. However, the answers only include $s=1$ as a valid solution. I know that $\ln(0)$ is undefined, but I thought that multiplying this answer by $0$ would make this a valid solution. Why is this not the case?

P.S Sorry if the tags are unrelated; this is my first time using Stack Exchange and I am not a maths whiz!!

Comment: "undefined" $\times 0$ is not $0$.  It's undefined.

Comment: You cannot do *any* manipulation on objects that are not defined, it doesn't make sense. You can ask questions about limits if you know such machinery, however.

Comment: Ah, alright. Thanks guys!!!

Answer (score 1):

The rule is, $0$ times any number is $0$.  However, you still need the second thing to be a number.   Because $\ln (0)$ is undefined,  we can't multiply it by anything.

You can think about it like putting the input into a machine.  0 goes in.  The machine then looks at $0^2(\ln 0)$.  As soon as it reaches $\ln (0)$, the machine crashes because it has no idea what to do with 0!

Answer (score 1):

If an expression is not defined, then it does not make sense to multiply it with another number. Hence, it is not true that the product of an undefined expression and $0$ is $0$. This is like if I asked you
$$
\text{"What is the answer to $\text{purple}\times0$?"}
$$
The correct answer would be: "that doesn't make any sense", not "it's $0$".

Comment: I'm not sure that that's true in all cases. Can't we evaluate $0\sin(\frac{1}{0})$?

Comment: @JohnJoy: $1/0$ is not defined, and so it is certainly not a real number. Therefore, it is not in the domain of $\sin$. Hence, $\sin(1/0)$ is not defined. And $\sin(1/0)$ is not a real number either, meaning that it is not in the domain of the multiplication function. Therefore, $0\sin(1/0)$ is undefined. We can say that $\lim_{x \to 0}x\sin(1/x)=0$, but that's only because, when dealing with limits, we only care about the behaviour of a function near a point, not at that point.